# Motion sensored speaker with display screen?

Tags: sensors

I want to create a motion sensored system, if the motion sensor detects motion it will make a speaker play a sound and a screen will record the time. This needs to be a loop that turns on for x number of hours and off for z number of hours. 
Also, I need the speaker to loop through different sounds...

I'm new to this sort of programming so any help anyone can give me on how to write this code would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The scope of this question is far too broad.  Breakdown you questions into the specific tasks.  When you have done that, try submitting questions showing what you have tried and what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Good project idea...This breaks down very nicely into parts that you can build and test individually.

First, I would start with the blink example, this will be helpful when debugging the other parts and it will guarantee that you have everything setup and can program the Arduino with the IDE.

Then there's the actual pieces to get the project working.

*Play a Sound
*Display Information 
*Record Time of Day
*Enable and Disable based on Elapsed Time or Time of Day
*Motion Sensing

To play a sound you have a couple of options.  The simplest would be to get a buzzer since you can control these right from an Arduino pin.  If you want to play a specific MP3 or wav file, you will need a slightly more involved setup.  Here is an example for playing a tone with a buzzer.  http://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/tone

For the motion sensing you probably want a PIR sensor.  You can find them everywhere (Ebay, Sparkfun, Adafruit, Amazon, etc).  You can also google Arduino PIR Example.  Here is one result. http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/PIRsense

Once you've got those two bits working you can play a tone, when motion is detected.  Next is the display.  Outputting to an LCD is pretty easy.  There's a few ways to do this.  You may want to find a tutorial for the specific LCD screen that you decide to buy.  (While you are looking, check out the OLED screens from Adafruit, they are pretty neat).  Anyway, get the screen working in code by itself, then you can connect it to the rest of your system to print something when you trigger the motion sensor and play the tone.

So, the timing...This is a little more involved.  The Arduino does not have a real time clock (RTC) so it can't tell the time.  You would have to get a separate RTC module and set the time on it.  I haven't worked with those before but...there are a few ways to interact with time.  If motion is triggered, you can check the time and if it is between the times that are valid (which you would define) then trigger the speaker, otherwise don't.

Once you can get the time from the RTC, you can display that information to the screen.

That should get you started.